# Count on multiple fields in multiple join on mysql select query

Tags: mysql

I want display total comments, total likes, total dislikes on a note in note detail page. Following are three tables from which  am fetching data.

> **tbl_note_actions**
>   `noteaction_note_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `noteaction_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `noteaction_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1->like, 0->dislike',
>     PRIMARY KEY (`noteaction_note_id`,`noteaction_user_id`)
>
> **tbl_notes_comments**
>     `notepost_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `notepost_note_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
>     `notepost_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `notepost_message` text NOT NULL,
>     `notepost_rating` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>     `notepost_parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `notepost_added_on` datetime NOT NULL,
>     `notepost_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
>     `notepost_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>    PRIMARY KEY (`notepost_id`)
>
> **tbl_notes**
>     `note_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `note_notetype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `note_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `note_description` text NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (`note_id`)

It showing wrong counts for total likes, total dislikes and total comments.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    note_id,
    note_notetype_id,
    note_user_id,
    note_name,
    note_description,
    COUNT( DISTINCT notepost_note_id) AS totComments,
    note_id,
    count(if(noteaction_type = 1, noteaction_note_id, NULL)) AS totlikes,
    count( if(noteaction_type = 0, noteaction_note_id, NULL)) AS totdislikes
FROM `tbl_notes`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_users`
    ON user_id= note_user_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_courses`
    ON course_id = note_course_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_universities`
    ON university_id = note_university_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_note_types`
    ON notetype_id = note_notetype_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_note_actions`
    ON noteaction_note_id = note_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_notes_posts`
    ON notepost_note_id = note_id
WHERE `note_id` = '4'
GROUP BY note_id, notepost_id
```

which results likes 1, dislikes 1 and comments 1 but actually it should be likes 1, dislikes 1 and comments 4.

Please help me to resolve it

Thanks

Comment: please use alias when you are using join

Comment: table fields have already distinct name so I think no need to use alias names. Please update me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: can you provide table structure ?

Comment: it is already posted in question

Answer (score 0):

Dear i want to know one thing why you using DISTINCT  **COUNT( DISTINCT notepost_note_id) AS totComments** because if i have one post which have multiple comment then you use DISTINCT it will return 1 value always for that post

Remove DISTINCT and check

Comment: can you please give me field of tbl_notes_posts

Comment: I apologies tbl_notes_comments is actually  tbl_notes_posts

Comment: please replace COUNT( DISTINCT notepost_note_id) AS totComments, with these one COUNT( DISTINCT notepost_id) AS totComments,

Comment: I have tried this time comments dhows accurate count i.e. 4 but likes and dislikes showing 24 each which should be

Count: 4
Likes 2
Dislikes: 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115397/discussion-between-atul-sharma-and-dhaval-bhavsar).

Answer (score 0):

try this It may help you

```
         SELECT
    note_id,
    note_notetype_id,
    note_user_id,
    note_name,
    note_description,
    noteCount.totalComment AS totComments,
    note_id,
    count(if(noteaction_type = 1, noteaction_note_id, NULL)) AS totlikes,
    count( if(noteaction_type = 0, noteaction_note_id, NULL)) AS totdislikes
FROM `tbl_notes`

LEFT JOIN (
                         SELECT note_id,count(notepost_note_id) as totalComment
                         FROM tbl_notes  
                         GROUP BY note_id
         ) AS noteCount ON noteCount.note_id=tbl_notes.note_id
```

Comment: IFNULL(COUNT( DISTINCT notepost_note_id), 0) AS "totComments",